# change datetime field to return unix timestamp in django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, datetime, serialization, django-rest-framework, timestamp

I want to get a timestamp that is represented in milliseconds or seconds in order to convert it to a DateTime javascript object on the frontend. If there is a way to convert this format
`"timestamp" : "2020-11-06T10: 51: 10Z"`  to a javascript DateTime object just tell me. If I need to use a separate serializer for the DateTime, how do I use a serializer in a serializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `to_representation` method in your serializer if you don't like the default string representation:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['id', 'your_datetime_field']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        formatted_datetime_field = instance.your_datetime_field.timestamp()

        return {'id': instance.id,
                'your_datetime_field': instance.formatted_datetime_field}
```

This will give you the Unix time, in seconds. JavaScript's Date objects work in milliseconds so you can multiply the result by 1000 to make it work on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different but in my opinion more simple solution would be:

```
    date = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_date_timestamp')

      def get_date_timestamp(self, instance):
          return instance.date.timestamp()
```

Comment: I dont remember what was it but I think I fixed it 3 years ago

Comment: It's great that you fixed it 3 years ago but as you may notice by the amount of views, there might be people who still hasn't fixed it